# Uncountable intersection of uncountable sets

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C \subseteq [0,1]$ be uncountable. Show that there exists $a \in (0,1)$ such that $C \cap [a,1]$ is uncountable.

I'm not sure what the right approach is. The couple options I came up with are:

1) Pick some $a$ and find some bijection between $C \cap [a,1]$ and another uncountable set.

2) Assume the negation of the claim (so any choice of $a \in (0,1)$ is such that $C \cap [a,1]$ is countable), then show that this implies that $C$ is countable.

In either case I don't really know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $C\cap[a,1]$ is always countable no matter what number $a$ is, then $C\cap \left[ \frac 1 n, 1 \right]$ is countable no matter which **positive integer** $n$ is.  Therefore
$$
C\cap\left[ \frac 1 2 , 1 \right], \quad C\cap\left[ \frac 1 3,  \frac 1 2 \right], \quad C\cap\left[ \frac 1 4,  \frac 1 3 \right], \quad C\cap\left[ \frac 1 5,  \frac 1 4 \right], \quad \ldots
$$
are all countable. Therefore their union is countable (since there are just countably many of these sets).  But their union is
$$
C\cap (0,1].
$$
And the difference between that and $C\cap [0,1]$ is at most one point, and adding one point won't make a set uncountable.

Answer (score 2):

$a=\frac{1}{n}$ works for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Indeed,
$$ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\Big(C\cap[\frac{1}{n},1]\Big)=C\setminus\{0\} $$
hence is uncountable. But if each $C\cap[\frac{1}{n},1]$ were countable, then the union would be as well.